# How to do a SQL select statement with where clause is in csv format?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am passing in a dynamic number of id's in csv format as a sql parameter and want to use them in a where clause for a select statement.

I can't get my head around how to do this in sql.

Pseudocode would look something like this:

```
@ids varchar(max)

select stuff from table
where stuff =  each.@ids.split(',')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ok after a bit of research i think that the best way to do this is with xml rather than csv's since it will be less effort so I am going to select the best answer and close this. Thanks guys.

Comment: ... That's going to depend on your DB, application language, and connection driver, none of which you've provided.  Often, though, you can't just provide an array (perhaps in an effort to encourage `JOIN`s?) - you either have to list a specific number of parameters, or construct the query dynamically (more difficult, and a little dangerous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want to pass a dynamic list then in SQL Server create a table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ParseIds (@ids varchar(MAX)) RETURNS @TempIds TABLE (Id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Pos INT 
    SET     @Pos = 1

    SET     @ids = ',' + @ids + ','

    WHILE   @Pos < LEN(@ids)
    BEGIN
            INSERT  @TempIds 
            VALUES (Convert(int, SUBSTRING(@ids,@Pos+1,CHARINDEX(',',@ids,@Pos+1)-@Pos-1)))

            SET     @Pos = CHARINDEX(',',@ids,@Pos+1)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Pass your dynamic CSV Id list into your stored proc and use in query like this:

```
select stuff from table
where stuff IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.ParseIds(@ids))
```

Answer (score 0):

the `IN` query does what you need:

```
SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE stuff in (1,4,7,9)
```

Consider SQL-Injection if you constuct the SQL from insecure sources (@ids entered by users etc.)

Comment: That does not work when passing a string variable (`@ids varchar(max)`) to the `IN` statement. It has to be parsed.